How to override controller gracefully in springboot
My springboot version is 2.7.0
In maven multi module project, I have two modules named A and B, B dependency A.
In module A , there is a Controller such as
@Api(tags = "share api")
public interface ShareAPI {

   public void share(ShareDTO dto);

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/share")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ShareAPI.class)
public class ShareController implements ShareAPI {

  @PutMapping("")
  @Override
  public void share(@RequestBody ShareDTO share){
    // do something
  }

  // ... other methods

}

@Data
public class ShareDTO {
 
   private String url;

}


In module B, I want to expand the capabilities of the share method in ShareController: A new field for userId needs to be added to the parameters.
So I make a new DTO extends ShareDTO and add a userId field to the new DTO
@Data
public class ShareAdditionalDTO extends ShareDTO{
 
   private String userId;

}


and a new controller in module B:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/share")
public class ShareAdditionalController extends ShareController {

  @Override
  @PutMapping("/additional")
  public void shareAdditional(@RequestBody ShareAdditionalDTO share){
    // do something
  }

}


The requirement has been met, but I feel it's not elegant:
users can access both the share and share/additional services, but the share service has actually become obsolete. Now, we only need to retain the share/additional service. Alternatively, the share/additional service should not exist; users should still be accessing the share service, but with the option to include an additional userId parameter.
So how can I make it gracefully, Especially in Swagger, I only want to display the one service that is active.
Thanks in advance

If I understand it correctly you want to be able to have module c with dependency on module a, this would have the ShareController as default. And module d with dependency on b would have the ShareAdditionalController as default? That’s why you annotate with ConditionalOnMissingBean?

It's expected that ShareAdditionalController also provides the same mapping for /share because you are extending ShareController (without overriding it) and so also it's mapping for /share.
Maybe you only meant to implement the ShareAPI interface in the ShareAdditionalController (that is what the @Override above the shareAdditional method suggests)? But then the infix of "Additional" in the class and the method names would be misleading.
The best practice would be to version the API (from the beginning), mark the old as deprecated, provide the new API for a limited time in parallel, and then replace the old API with an implementation that returns an appropriate 301 response.
